# Elastic Beanstalk ENONET

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a question regarding Elastic Beanstalk: I have the problem deploying my code to production.  I have attached a screenshot from EB of the error codes I get.
It seems to be related to an ENONET on an lstat and node but I did not change anything in the code and suddenly it is not working anymore.

I have checked the logs and there s nothing for node.js

Have you ever encountered this error?

[image: Error code]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it can't clone from the github repo for some reason.